# Can anybody tell me why this is happening in c language

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {

     float a=10;
    printf("%f"+1,a);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output -- d

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {

     float a=10;
    printf("%f"+36,a);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output -- p

When ever i change the value of +1 it gives different outputs....   Explain me why

Comment: You forgot to ask your compiler for all warnings and debug info. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (and then the compiler would have warned you).

Comment: BTW, http://floating-point-gui.de/ is a useful read

Comment: What do you actually think the `+1` and `+36` are doing?  You're not changing the number you're trying to print, and you're not (really) changing the format string you're trying to print with, either.  You're doing some very strange pointer arithmetic, that can't possible result in useful or properly-working code.  Are you just trying weird things in an attempt to learn from them, or what? [P.S. I *can* tell you why this is happening, if you really want to know, but first you have to explain what you're really trying to do.]

Comment: By the way, I assume there's a typo in the first example.  I would expect that code to print `f`, not `d`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anybody tell me why this is happening in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015392/can-anybody-tell-me-why-this-happening-in-c)  The difference is the choice of format string `"%d"` vs `"%f"` and variable type.  And the user who asked.  Both would benefit from a newline at the end of the format string.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly are you trying to accomplish.

If you want to do the sum, you just have to do it after the comma:

from this:

```
printf("%f"+36,a);
```

to this:

```
printf("%f",a+36);
```

The same for the other sum.

Comment: If this worked for you, please accept it as answer.

And, to whoever downvoted my answer: please consider leaving a comment on how it can be improved; I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote might have been because we have no way of knowing if this is what the OP was actually trying to do.  I'm upvoting now so I can vote to close the OP's second ask of the same question (at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015392/can-anybody-tell-me-why-this-happening-in-c) as a dup of this one.

Comment: @SteveSummit you are completely right, my answer works ONLY IF that's the problem the OP has. There aren't many details, so who knows what (s)he's trying to do. Also, I didn't see the other question before, but the OP has changed `float` for `int` so maybe (s)he is just trying to figure random stuff out using SO instead of a guide; who knows. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely compile with all warnings. I used `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`. It didn't compile with my warnings because there are too many arguments for printf.

When I tested out the code you posted, it printed 'f' and 'A???'. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but I believe it has to do with how your float is adding with the number to give you an Ascii character.

Answer (score 0):

The output is different every time because it is undefined to read from an unknown address.

*Compare with this code:*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   printf("Hello,World\n"+1);
}
```

It looks like the famous *Hello,World* but in fact it is the less known version *ello,World*. The argument to `printf` is string or more precisely a pointer to a null terminated sequence of chars in memory, when `"Hello"+1` is evaluated, the pointer is incremented by one and points to `"ello,World"`.

Your program will first print the the string "f" and in the second case is a memory overrun error, it will print whatever is found in the memory location 36 bytes away from the string. This random memory location is likely to have a different contents every time.