# Can anybody tell me why this happening in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {

     int a=10;
    printf("%d"+1,a);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output. --- d

```
#include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {

    #include <stdio.h>
 //Compiler version gcc 6.3.0

 int main(void)
 {

     int a=10;
    printf("%d"+36,a);

    return 0;
 }
```

Output. --- p

Explain me why this happening...   Whenever i change value of +1 it print different outputs...

Comment: `Int` isn't a type (though `int` is). In any event, your formatting is awful. Please fix.

Comment: @PySerialKiller That's not correct.

Comment: Next time, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` to get warnings and debug info.

Comment: Please tell the rest of your class to not post this to SO.

Answer (score 6):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

`"%d"+1` actually is adding 1 to a `const char*` pointer (the literal `"%d"` will decay to a `const char*` pointer under certain circumstances), which actually takes you to the `d` in that string literal! The `printf` formatter is therefore not appropriate for your arguments.

`"%d"+36` is simply going to do very bad things indeed, since you don't own the memory 36 places on from the start of `"%d"`

Don't you mean something like `printf("%d", a + 1);` &c.?

Lastly, what the deuce is an `Int`? Didn't you mean `int`?

Comment: And `printf("%d"+36,a);` brings you to your kernel code.